# Can I set up Ubuntu server openstack for a private cloud on a single computer with two hard drives?

Tags: server, openstack

That's all there is to it I guess. All I need to know is is it possible, and is it hard?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to use devstack:  http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html